# Django-Admin startproject command line not working

Tags: python, django

I updated my Python version to the latest version of 3.11.3 and updated my Django version to 4.2. When I try to make a new project the django-admin startproject command line doesn't work.

I tried running my gitbash in admin and resetting my pc.

Comment: So I changed my version of Python to 3.9 and when I download Django and want to create a new project im still getting an error. I tried completely uninstalling django and reinstalling it but i am still getting the same error.

Comment: django-admin startproject project
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

Answer (score 0):

I'd make sure you have python added to your path. This link should help you do that on any OS: https://realpython.com/add-python-to-path/

You should also ensure you don't have multiple python versions in your environment variables since they will conflict if you have multiple paths. Make sure it's just the latest version.

You can learn more about environment variables here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.3